# Symfony ChoiceType $choices - labels and values swapped

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

Symfony 2.8.2

According to the Symfony docs "The choices option is an array, where the array key is the item's label and the array value is the item's value"

http://symfony.com/doc/2.8/reference/forms/types/choice.html#choices

But with the following form I'm seeing the exact opposite:

```
        $filterForm = $this->createFormBuilder()
        ->add('vendorName', ChoiceType::class, array(
            'expanded' => true,
            'multiple' => true,
            'choices'  => array('label' => 'value') // <-- HERE
        ))
        ->add('filter', SubmitType::class, array('label' => 'Filter'))
        ->getForm();
```

Renders like this:

[image: Label is value and the value is label]

Is the documentation wrong? Or am I not getting it right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In newer Symfony versions die Option `choices_as_values` is deprecated.

https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/14951

here is an explanation. I think in your case you have to switch it or use the option so long you can.

Set `choices_as_values` to `true`. If you upgrade you have to change that.

> @Soullivaneuh choices_as_values is not directly to choice_label. So you are talking about a different topic.
>   choices_as_values controls where the choices are the keys or the values in the choices option. Symfony 2.0 shipped with choices as keys (and labels as values), which means that the easy syntax only works when your choices are integers or strings. Any other case (boolean choices for instance) required passing a ChoiceList object instead, making the usage more complex (especially for people forgetting that booleans cannot be used as keys as PHP just casts them to string silently).
>   This is the reason why this option has been introduced in 2.7 to be able to flip the array (while maintaining BC). the advantage is that any type of data can be used in this way (strings, integers, floats, booleans, objects, arrays)

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. So I guess my options are either set choices_as_values to true or upgrade to 3.x. Can you, please, reflect that in your answer

Comment: @StasParshin correct, set choices_as_values true in order to have the keys as labels. Starting with v3, keys as labels is the default.

Answer (score 1):

As of Symfony 4 "choices_as_values" is no longer supported:
https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/14951

You would have to use this to achieve the same:

```
            'choice_label' => function ($value) {
                return $value;
            },
```