# Does anyone know why Symfony ChoiceType choices list keep labels as the array keys rather than values?

Tags: php, symfony

Does anyone know why Symfony ChoiceType choices list keep labels as the array keys rather than values?

I looked but wasn't able to find the reasoning behind that decision. Since the option label might contain lot's of special characters and be fairly long, whereas, the choice value, in most of the cases, is either an int or a small String used for Enum types.

Comment: Answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44631005/5349893

Comment: Thank you, I saw this answer, but I was not able to quite understand. Since ChoiceType is used to create either a dropdown or checkboxes, or radiobuttons, which values are either strings or integers, what is the point of adding the possibility to pass as values other types of objects, like boolean or Objects? Wouldn't the HTML cast them to int or string if possible?

Comment: Consider it a mystery and move on.  You might be amused to discover that in S2 the array keys were indeed the values.  Then someone got bored and flipped them.  Symfony has done a great job at being consistent and avoiding bc breaks but sometimes the jolly jokers win.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason behind this relates to how PHP deals with certain values like `null` and booleans as array keys. This will lead to inconsistent behaviour:

```
php > $a = [true => 'Yes', false => 'No', null => 'Empty'];
php > var_dump($a);
array(3) {
  [1]=>
  string(3) "Yes"
  [0]=>
  string(2) "No"
  [""]=>
  string(8) "Empty"
}

php > $a = [false => 'Empty', 0 => 'No', 1 => 'Yes', 2 => 'Maybe'];
php > var_dump($a);
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(2) "No"
  [1]=>
  string(3) "Yes"
  [2]=>
  string(5) "Maybe"
}
```

As you can see in the second example this can even lead to keys being overwritten by accident. In order to avoid these issues Symfony decided to reverse the value/label-mapping to label/value as labels pretty much always are strings and thus can be handled more reliably than the values.

If you run into problems with long label names you can use short translation keys that are expanded into the long version using the translation component instead.

Comment: This answer seems quite speculative.  There are many many cases in php where trying to mix booleans and nulls and integers and empty strings will result in amusing edge cases.  Someone trying to use your example would quickly realize the problem and adjust accordingly.  Keep in mind that value => label worked fine for a number of years.  Any explanation as to why it was suddenly flipped would have to address this fact.

Comment: It makes more sense if you take my examples further. You might want to have a callable or an object, e.g. an Entity with a `__toString()` as value, but these can't be used as array keys in the choices array. My explanation why previously value => label-arrays were used more commonly is that callables were not a thing back then and object oriented PHP is fairly new as well, although admittedly it was already a thing when Symfony Forms used the other array-style.

Comment: Thanks very much :)