# Unable to reverse value for property path [...]: The choice [...] does not exist or is not unique

Tags: php, symfony

After updating from Symfony 2.8 to 3.0 and verifying the operation, it was found that the author could not save due to a validation error.

Probably due to a specification change that reverses the Choice Type key and value.

I tried putting  `choice_label` in the reference below, but it didn't work.

I also tried `array_flip` `$staffs`, but the display changed and I couldn't save it.

Is there any other way?

[Symfony ChoiceType $choices - labels and values swapped](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44630752/symfony-choicetype-choices-labels-and-values-swapped)

Error

```
This value is not valid.

Unable to reverse value for property path "author":
 The choice "9" does not exist or is not unique.
```

Before StaffChoicelist

```
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\ChoiceList\ChoiceList;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\ChoiceList\LazyChoiceList;

class StaffChoiceList extends LazyChoiceList
{
    public function __construct($staffService, $loginStaff)
    {
        $this->staffService = $staffService;
        $this->loginStaff = $loginStaff;
    }

    public function setCurrentStaff($currentStaff)
    {
        $this->currentStaff = $currentStaff;
    }

    public function loadChoiceList($value = null)
    {
        // Get the same shop staff as the login staff
        $staffs = $this->staffService->getStaffByShop($this->loginStaff->getShop());

        If the current staff is not included in the acquired staff (due to transfer etc.), add it to the end
        if ($this->currentStaff && !array_search($this->currentStaff, $staffs)) {
            $staffs[] = $this->currentStaff;
        }
            return new ChoiceList($staffs, $staffs);
    }
}
```

After StaffChoiceloader

```php
use Symfony\Component\Form\ChoiceList\Loader\ChoiceLoaderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Choicelist\ArrayChoiceList;

class StaffChoiceLoader implements ChoiceLoaderInterface
{
    public function loadChoiceList($value = null)
    {
        $staffs = $this->staffService->getStaffByShop($this->loginStaff->getShop());

        if ($this->currentStaff && !array_search($this->currentStaff, $staffs)) {
            $staffs[] = $this->currentStaff;
        }
            return new arrayChoiceList($staffs, null);
    }
    public function loadChoicesForValues(array $values, $value = null)
    {
        // Optimized when no data is preset
        if (empty($choices))
        {
            return array();
        }

        $values = array();
        foreach ($choices as $choice)
        {
            $values[] = (string) $this->loginStaff->getId();
        }

        return $values;
    }

    public function loadValuesForChoices(array $choices, $value = null)
    {
        // Optimized when nothing is sent
        if (empty($values))
        {
            return array();
        }

        // Get the entity from the ID and return the required data
        return $this->staffService->getStaffByShop($this->loginStaff->getShop());
    }
}
```

Type

```php
        $authorChoiceList = new StaffChoiceLoader($this->staffService, $options['login_staff']);
        $builder->add("author", EntityType::class, array(
            "required" => true,
            "class" => "AppBundle:Staff",
            "choice_loader" => $authorChoiceList,
            "choice_label" =>function ($value) {
              return $value;
            },
        ));
        $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA, function (FormEvent $event) use ($authorChoiceList) {
            $article = $event->getData();
            $authorChoiceList->setCurrentStaff($article->getAuthor());
        });
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            "validation_groups" => function (FormInterface $form) {
                $article = $form->getData();
                return $this->getValidationGroups($article->getArticleStatus());
            },
        ));
    }
```

Staff.php

```php
    /**
     * __toString
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function __toString()
    {
        return $this->staffName;
    }
    /**
     * Set staffName
     *
     * @param string $staffName
     * @return Staff
     */
    public function setStaffName($staffName)
    {
        $this->staffName = $staffName;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get staffName
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getStaffName()
    {
        return $this->staffName;
    }
```

Article.php

```php
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Staff")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="author_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=true)
     */
    protected $author;
    /**
     * Set author
     *
     * @param \AppBundle\Model\Entity\Staff $author
     * @return Article
     */
    public function setAuthor(\AppBundle\Model\Entity\Staff $author = null)
    {
        $this->author = $author;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get author
     *
     * @return \AppBundle\Model\Entity\Staff
     */
    public function getAuthor()
    {
        return $this->author;
    }
```

**Tried Code**
Type

```php
    public function __construct($staffService, array $options = [])
    {
        $this->staffService = $staffService;
        $this->loginStaff = $options['login_staff'];
        $this->currentStaff = $options['login_staff'];
    }
```

Error

```
Notice: Undefined index: login_staff
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try make it simple first. If your *ChoiceLoader* doesn't work, try to avoid it. After you get minimal working example you can refactor it.

*EntityType* is usefull only if you use *QueryBuilder* for obtaining choices from database.

Use *ChoiceType* as in example below:

```
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\ChoiceType;
use App\Entity\Staff;

class StaffType extends AbstractType
{
    public function __construct($staffService)
    {
        $this->staffService = $staffService;
    }

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
    {
        $currentStaff = $options['currentStaff'];
        $loginStaff = $options['loginStaff'];
    
        $staff = $this->staffService->getStaffByShop($loginStaff->getShop());
        // If the current staff is not included in the acquired staff (due to transfer etc.), add it to the end
        if ($currentStaff && !array_search($currentStaff, $staffs)) {
            $staff[] = $currentStaff;
        }
    
        $builder->add('author', ChoiceType::class, [
            'choices' => $staffs,
            'choice_label' => function(Staff $employee, $key) {
                return $employee->getName();
            }
        ]);
    }
}
```

Staff array must contains unique keys e.g.:

```
$staff = [
    1 => new Staff(1),
    2 => new Staff(2),
    3 => new Staff(3),  
];
```

Build your form in controller with custom options:

```
$options = [
    'currentStaff' => $currentStaff,
    'loginStaff' => $loginStaff,
];
$this->createForm(StaffType::class, $data, $options);
```

For accessing *$this->staffService* use **dependency injection** in your form type. And for *$this->currentStaff* and *$this->loginStaff* use *$options*.

Does it works for you? If not, please provide structure of $staff array.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried it, but I'm stumbling on dependency injection. How do I inject ```$options```? I've added the code I tried, so can you check it out?

Comment: DI is suitable only for services. To pass custom options use *options* parameter in *buildForm* method of form type. Check my edited answer.

Comment: I tried it, but I got the following error: ```The value of type "object" cannot be converted to a valid array key.``` It seems that ```$staff``` is an object. When I did ```var_dump```, it became as follows. ```array(17) { [0]=> object(AppBundle\Model\Entity\Staff)#650 (24) { ["id":protected]=> int(305)...```  It seems that this is because each item of array is an object of StaffEntity.

Answer (score 0):

```
    $staffs = $this->staffService->getStaffByShop($this->loginStaff->getShop());
```

This stands out to me as being different in the coding, specifically the second query.

Answer (score 0):

```
    protected $password;
    protected $dbName;
    public function __construct ( $UserName, $Password, $DbName ) {
      $this->userName = $UserName;
      $this->password = $Password;...   
    {
                public function __construct($staffService, $loginStaff)
            {
                $this->staffService = $staffService;
                
                $this->loginStaff = $loginStaff;
            }
                public function setCurrentStaff($currentStaff)
            {
                $this->currentStaff = $currentStaff
            }
        
                public function loadChoiceList($value = True)
            {
                // Get the same shop staff as the login staff
                $staffs = $this->staffService->getStaffByShop($this->loginStaff->getShop($staff);
        
                If the current staff is not included in the acquired staff (due to transfer etc.), add it to the end if ($this->currentStaff && !array_search($this->currentStaff, $staffs)) 
        {
                $staffs = $this->currentStaff;
                }
        
        {
                return new ChoiceList($staffs, $staffs);
                }    Set choices_as_values to true. If you upgrade you have to change that.
```