# Symfony2.8: choices_as_values doesn't work

Tags: php, symfony

`Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\ChoiceList\ChoiceList` and `Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\ChoiceList\LazyChoiceList` have been rewritten in Symfony2.8 (details in the post below).
After that, a validation error occurred in Symfony3 and the save of the author selected in the form failed.
I attributed it to the swapping of the Choice Type keys and values.
So, before raising Symfony, I specified `chouces_as_values` as Type and verified whether it works.
But it didn't work and the result was similar. In other words, can we think that this is not a replacement of key values?
It may be that the rewriting of ChoiceList has failed.
Also, I would like advice on where to debug so that you can understand what is the cause.

[Symfony: Unable to reverse value for property path [...]: The choice [...] does not exist or is not unique](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66778990/symfony-unable-to-reverse-value-for-property-path-the-choice-does)

https://symfony.com/doc/2.8/reference/forms/types/choice.html#choices-as-values
ArticleType

```php
       $ChoiceList = new StaffChoiceLoader($this->staffService, $options['login_staff']);
     //$ChoiceList = new StaffChoiceList($this->staffService, $options['login_staff']);

        $builder->add("author", "entity", array(
            "required" => true,
            "class" => "AppBundle:Staff",
            "choice_loader" => $ChoiceList,
            //"choice_list" => $ChoiceList,
            "empty_value" => "Please select",
            //Add
            "choices_as_values" => true,
        ));
```

ArticleEntity

```php
    /**
     * author
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Staff")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="author_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=true)
     */
    protected $author;
```

Comment: I am not sure I understand the question. What exactly happens and what did you expect instead? Can you please also share the code of your `StaffChoiceList` class?

Comment: @xabbuh Thanks for your comment. The explanation was insufficient, so I added it. For ```StaffChoiceList```, can you refer to the posted post?