# Attempted to call an undefined method named "getChoices" of class "Symfony\Component\Form\ChoiceList\View\ChoiceListView"

Tags: php, symfony

In the app updated from Symfony 2.3 to 2.8, we have changed the choice list that changed in 2.7.
See the links below for documentation on previous code and changes.

I got the following error in it.
Does this mean I have to create `getChoices` in StaffChoiceLoader?
I think only `loadChoiceList`, `loadChoicesForValues`,  `loadValuesForChoices` required for ChoieLoaderInterface is needed.

Beforecode
[Symfony: Unable to reverse value for property path [...]: The choice [...] does not exist or is not unique](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66778990/symfony-unable-to-reverse-value-for-property-path-the-choice-does)

Document
https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/2.8/UPGRADE-2.7.md

ChoiceLoader.php

```php
class StaffChoiceLoader implements ChoiceLoaderInterface
{
    public function loadChoiceList($value = null)
    {
        $staffs = $this->staffService->getStaffByShop($this->loginStaff->getShop());

        $factory = new DefaultChoiceListFactory();

        $choiceList = $factory->createListFromChoices($staffs);

        $choiceListView = $factory->createView(
           $choiceList,
           function ($staffs, $key) use ($staffs) {
           return $staffs[$key];
        });

            return $choiceListView;
    }
}
```